# Low beam not working in headlight

Tags: electrical, headlight, miata

I have a 1999 Miata, i bought the car for 750$ as a project car. it had some body damage but i figured i would fix it. The car is mostly done now, but i have one major issue. The low beams in my passenger side headlight does not work, but the high beam does. The drivers side is OK both low and high beams. also the orange blinker light in the passenger side light is straight on and it does blink when i activate them. In the drivers side in the other hand, its not on and it only works when i activate it.

Comment: how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Are low beam and high beam bulbs separate? If there are two different bulbs, you may check low beam bulb and then the wiring.

Comment: @coner They are the same bulb; that's why i am really confused.

Comment: maybe high beam coil of the bulb is problematic maybe? Can you test the bulb with battery or adapter?

Comment: @coner Turns out it was the bulb, i did not know they had two parts in them, I'm an idiot!

Answer (score 2):

The most likely causes of a problem like this are:

- A failed bulb.
- A poor or failed earth (this often results in the wrong lamp lighting up)
- A broken wire in the harness.

Checking the bulb should always be your first task, as these are cheap and (usually) easy to replace. Tracking down poor earths or broken wires requires a bit of work, a multimeter and some spare lengths of wire can help to narrow down the culprit...